# Numba and astropy.units.Quantity

Tags: python, numba, astropy

Is there a simple way of using `@numba.njit`/`@numba.jit` with a function which operates on `astropy.units.Quantity` objects?

```py
from numba import jit
import astropy.units as u
import numpy as np

a = np.linspace(0,1,3)*u.m
b = np.linspace(1,10,3)*u.m

@jit
def test(x,y):
    z = np.empty_like(x)
    for i in range(x.size):
        z[i] = x[i]+y[i]
    return z

test(a,b)
```

returns:

```
array([ 1.,  6., 11.])
```

i.e. it strips away any unit information. It seems that it internally converts the quantities back into regular numpy arrays.

In more complex scenarios, where there is any unit manipulation taking place within
the function, `njit` simply fails and `jit` falls back to "object mode". E.g.

```py
from numba import jit
import astropy.units as u
import numpy as np

a = np.linspace(0,1,3)*u.m
b = np.linspace(1,10,3)*u.s

@jit
def test(x,y):
    z = np.empty_like(x)/y.unit
    for i in range(x.size):
        z[i] = x[i]/y[i]
    return z

test(a,b)
```

Output:

```
<ipython-input-29-dc9284dd75e6>:8: NumbaWarning: 
Compilation is falling back to object mode WITH looplifting enabled because Function "test" failed type inference due to: Unknown attribute 'unit' of type array(float64, 1d, C)
...
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you have a more non-trivial use case for this?  You example function is already vectorized by Numpy and could be written `z = x / y`--there's no need for the `for` loop in this case.  So I don't know that there'd be much advantage gained from Numba in this case (unless you are angling for a different execution target, like a GPU).  Of course, regardless it's still an open question as to how to use Numba with `Quantity`.

Comment: The "easy" answer would be to have a wrapper that first make sure that your Quantities are already in compatible units, then call the `@jit` function just on the plain ndarray values (`Quantity.value`), then re-apply the units to the result.  You might also be able to adapt `Quantity` to a [`jitclass`](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/jitclass.html) somehow, but I don't have enough expertise with numba to know how to make that work effectively.